# Issue with executing tests for main function in Go

Tags: go, go-testing

I wrote this test a few months back and it was running successfully without any error and never went through init() function as I have only invoked handler function from test but now it's failing with below error:

```
/usr/local/opt/go/libexec/bin/go tool test2json -t /private/var/folders/wt/fc27nzn51rdbvwvjzkl05hlc0000gs/T/GoLand/___TestHandleRequest_in_next_api_cmd_getAllRawTransportOrders.test -test.v -test.paniconexit0 -test.run ^\QTestHandleRequest\E$
{"level":"fatal","msg":"no configuration found:  not set","time":"2023-08-27T22:48:03+05:30"}

Process finished with the exit code 1
```

and I know that test is invoking init() function but then why it wasn't earlier. Am I missing something to understand here?

**init.go**

```
//go:build !test
// +build !test

package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "encoding/json"
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "os"

    "lib/storage/ssm"

    "next-api/aws/dynamodb"
    "next-api/cmd/utils"
    "next-api/config"
    "next-api/http"
)

func init() {
    // Log as JSON instead of the default ASCII formatter.
    log.SetFormatter(&log.JSONFormatter{})

    // Output to stdout instead of the default stderr
    // Can be any io.Writer, see below for File example
    log.SetOutput(os.Stdout)

    // Only log the warning severity or above.
    log.SetLevel(log.InfoLevel)

    var err error
    paramsRepo := ssm.NewRepository()

    configID, err := utils.GetEnv("CONFIG_ID")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("no configuration found: ", err)
    }

    cfg, err = config.Load(configID, paramsRepo)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("could not load config: ", err)
    }

    urls := http.URLs{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(cfg.MABES.URLs), &urls)

    // configure mTLS
    cert, err := tls.X509KeyPair([]byte(cfg.MABES.Certificate), []byte(cfg.MABES.PrivateKey))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("could not create MABES certificate: ", err)
    }

    MABES, err = http.NewMABESClient(urls, http.WithTLS(cert))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("could not create sofaClient client.", err)
    }

    NEXT = dynamodb.NewRepository(cfg.NEXT.Table)
}
```

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    gohttp "net/http"

    "next-api/api"
    "next-api/config"
    "next-api/errors"
    "next-api/http"
    "next-api/http/problem"
    "next-api/mabes"
    "next-api/next"
)

var (
    cfg   config.Config
    MABES mabes.Client
    NEXT  next.Repository
)

func main() {
    lambda.Start(handler)
}

func handler(request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    facilityID := request.PathParameters["facilityID"]
    if facilityID == "" {
        return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{
            StatusCode: gohttp.StatusBadRequest,
            Headers:    http.Headers("application/problem+json"),
            Body:       problem.ServerError(fmt.Errorf("missing facilityID parameter")).ToJSONResponse(),
        }, nil
    }

    transportOrders, err := api.GetAllRawTransportOrders(facilityID, request.QueryStringParameters, MABES, NEXT)
    b, err := json.Marshal(transportOrders)
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorln(err)

        if errors.Is(errors.NEXTRead, err) {
            return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{
                StatusCode: gohttp.StatusOK,
                Headers:    http.Headers("application/json"),
                Body:       fmt.Sprintf(`{"data":%s}`, string(b)),
            }, nil
        }

        return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{
            StatusCode: gohttp.StatusInternalServerError,
            Headers:    http.Headers("application/problem+json"),
            Body:       problem.ServerError(err).ToJSONResponse(),
        }, nil
    }

    return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{
        StatusCode: gohttp.StatusOK,
        Headers:    http.Headers("application/json"),
        Body:       fmt.Sprintf(`{"data":%s}`, string(b)),
    }, nil
}
```

**main_test.go**

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
    "testing"
    "time"

    "next-api/api"
    "next-api/mabes"
    "next-api/next"
)

func TestHandleRequest(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("should return the TransportOrders", func(t *testing.T) {
        req := events.APIGatewayProxyRequest{
            PathParameters: map[string]string{
                "facility": "11",
            },
        }
        timeStamp, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339))
        sofa1 := next.SofaTransferModel{}
        sofa1.Phase = "1"
        sofa1.PartKey.PartCode = "abcd"
        sofa1.PartKey.DispatcherFacility = "11"
        sofa1.PartKey.UsageCode = "01"
        sofa1.Storage.Number = "00315"
        sofa1.Shipment.RequestedArrivalDate = timeStamp.String()
        transportOrders := make([]next.SofaTransferModel, 0)
        transportOrders = append(transportOrders, sofa1)

        getAllRawTransportOrdersCalls := 0
        api.GetAllRawTransportOrders = func(facilityID string, params map[string]string, MABES mabes.Client, NEXT next.Repository) (next.SofaTransferObjects, error) {
            getAllRawTransportOrdersCalls++
            return transportOrders, nil
        }

        // when
        res, err := handler(req)
        // then
        assert.Equal(t, 1, getAllRawTransportOrdersCalls)

        assert.NoError(t, err)
        assert.Equal(t, http.StatusOK, res.StatusCode)

        assert.True(t, strings.Contains(res.Body, transportOrders[0].PartKey.PartCode))
        assert.True(t, strings.Contains(res.Body, transportOrders[0].Storage.Number))
    })

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Top level functions named `init` (all lowercase) are *always*, and *always* have been, executed *before* the test. The reason `init` fails now, even though it didn't before, it would appear, is a change in the environment; i.e. before `CONFIG_ID` was set, but now it isn't, at least not in the shell in which the test is being executed.

https://go.dev/ref/spec#Package_initialization

> The entire package is initialized by assigning initial values to all its package-level variables ***followed by calling all `init` functions in the order they appear in the source, possibly in multiple files, as presented to the compiler.***

---

If you run the `go test` command with `-tags test` the build constraints at the top of the `init.go` file, i.e. `//go:build !test`, will be respected and the file will be omitted from the test build. But by default, there is no "test" build tag and therefore without the `-tags test` argument those build constraints will be *ignored* and the `init.go` file will be included in the test build.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your answer! I would like to ask one more thing, is there a difference when you run "go test" and "go test -tags test" because when I am executing above test with "go test" then I could see the error but "go test -tags test" has a different behaviour and execution could reach till assertion statements.

Comment: my hypothesis is "-tags" was the reason it was skipping init() execution and allowing test to be green